.NET 4.8 Web Project with Azure Key Vaults as Config Builders slow to start - Visual Studio
I have web projects built in .NET 4.8 with Azure Key Vaults setup via config builders in the web configs i.e.:
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="${KEY_VAULT_NAME}" .../>
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
  <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
    <add key="KEY_VAULT_NAME" value="My-KeyVault" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
  </connectionStrings>

However - when loading the web project - it takes nearly around 3 minutes to load from Visual Studio 2022. I'm wondering if that's normal or is there any way to speed up this process as having to restart the application for changes can be time consuming.

What is the Visual Studio version you are using?

It's Visual Studio 2022

How you are retrieving the key value in code? Refer this SOthread once.

I think your KeyVault configuration is missing ..Check the above thread and try once.

@Harshitha - No the key vault is working fine - it's using an Azure account setup on Visual Studio to connect to Azure to get the key vault values fine. My question is can this be sped up on debugging the program?

AFAIK, this is the default and easy way to retrieve the keys. Can you please shaer the code once.

Visual Studio provides the easy and better approach to configure Key Vault from Connected Services.


Instead of configuring manually, follow the above steps. This provides the default configuration and installs only the required packages.

Refer this SOThread to get the clear steps.

Remove unnecessary packages, clear the bin folder, update the required packages to latest version, build and run the app again.



For the deployed App try creating the Azure Key vault in the same region where the App Service is deployed (or App in the same location as keyvault).

Set the App setting key name same as your KeyVault secret name.



 <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
   <add key="SecretTest" value="My-KeyVault" />
 </appSettings>


I am able to retrieve the secret without any delay.

Retrieve secret with App setting key name from config file using the below line of code (SecretTest is my appsetting key name),
 var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretTest"];


That's exactly what I'm doing - issue is project can sometimes take up to 3 minutes  when starting from Visual Studio with this added. Once it's running - key vault works fine

Check whether you have any pending updates for your Visual Studio.

@Harsthita I would do - but this is on a work computer so would have to require authorization to update versions - but could be something to look into.
